# Replacing a div's contents using a javascript function, noticing weirdness

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to run code which generates content using a function, and have the content be changeable onclick, but when the content is changed, none of the CSS is applied again. It's really odd.

Here's an example of my code, generalized:

```
function flush(divId) {
    $(divId).parentNode.removeChild(divId);
}

function makeContent(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    document.write('<div class="exampleClass" id="' + arg1 + 'Id">');
    if(arg3 < 1000) { // Chose an arbitrary number
        if (arg2 != "ArbritraryArg") {
            document.write('<span class="spanLink" onclick="flush(\'' + arg1 + 'Id\')\; makeContent(\'' + arg1 + '\',\'Something\',' + arg3 + ')\;">Blarg</span>');
        } else {
            document.write('<span class="spanLink" onclick="flush(\'' + arg1 + 'Id\')\; makeContent(\'' + arg1 + '\',\'SomethingElse\',' + arg3 + ')\;">Yearg</span>');
        }
    }

    var i = 0;
    var mdArray = eval(arg1 + 'Id' + arg3); // This is a multidimensional array which does exist just above the lines for function flush(). There are no possible problems in the array's definition, and so I did not include it here.
    do {
        document.write('<div class="exampleClass2">' + mdArray[i][0] + '</div><div class="exampleClass3">' + mdArray[i][1] + '</div>');
        i++;
    } while (i < mdArray.length);

    document.write('</div>');
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
    parentDiv.insertBefore(monster + 'Set',parentDiv.firstChild);
}

document.write('<div id="parentDiv">');
makeContent('Arg1','Something',Arg3);
document.write('</div>');
```

My problem is that, when I test by referencing this script file in a .html document, the first time makeContent() executes (when executed by the script itself), everything is perfect... But otherwise, not so. I've tested out the flush() function using an external `<span>` link that just calls the flush function, and it works fine, just removing the makeContent() data, and leaving everything else in the HTML document there.

So if I click on the `<span>` link generated in line 9 of the example code I've written, the content changes, but NONE of the relevant CSS is re-applied, and all other content in the HTML document disappears too. What's going on? This same issue happens if I try the same function using an external link along the same lines as how I tested flush().

Here's how I've got the HTML page, just in case anyone is wondering:

```
<html><head><title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head><body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,...</p>
<script href="script.js"></script>
<p><span class="spanLink" onclick="flush('Arg1Id');">Get rid of the content (TEST)</span></p>
<p><span class="spanLink" onclick="flush('Arg1Id'); makeContent('Arg1','Arg2',Arg3);">Try regenerating the content (TEST)</span></p>
</body></html>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

**Edit:** So I just noticed that on the test.html file, when I try to regenerate the content, the title changes from "Testing" to "test.html"... Is the newly generated content killing all HTML elements in the file?

Comment: document.write and inline click functions are usually to be avoided.  Instead, most people tag a div with an id, and then use document.getElementById() to retrieve the element for modification. Click functions should be in the javascript, not the HTML.

Comment: Can you post example code into jsFiddle and edit your question to include the link?  It may help people help you.  www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Avoid using `document.write()`. Using `innerHTML` method or even `.appendChild()` is preferable.

Comment: _Is the newly generated content killing all HTML elements?_ What do you see when you use the DOM inspector in Developer Tools or Firebug?

Comment: I noticed you have `$(divId)` in your `flush` method; are you using jQuery here?

Comment: @Barmar In Developer Tools, I see that most HTML elements have been stripped, yes. Really weird. Didn't think to use Dev Tools either, d'oh.

Comment: @Mathletics Yeah, I'm just starting to learn jQuery and I'm trying to include it when I can, just to get the hang of it. This whole thing is like a boredom project for while I've got nothing to do.

Comment: Simple DOM manipulation is one of jQuery's strengths; I'd recommend either taking it out or using it properly. The mess you've got here is sort of the antithesis of jQuery development.

Comment: That's the problem with `document.write()`. It overwrites the document.

Comment: @Paul I will try redoing the code to use innerHTML. I had no idea that document.write() was to be avoided. How do I replace inline click functions, though?

Comment: Anything in HTML can accept a unique id="someUniqueString" as a property.  You put that in your HTML, then in your javascript you fetch each item by id and set its onclick to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write should only be used while the page loads, if you trigger the event after the page loads, it will override your content and all your page will contain is that content. Instead try inserting the text into the DOM. Use innerHTML